# Fail2Ban doesn't seem to respond / ban IPs

Tags: iptables, sshd, fail2ban

So I have a server online and I am using Fail2Ban to ban IPs that are bruteforcing my server.
I did some testing today, and it seems that isn't the case.

Let's start from the beginning.

```
> sudo fail2ban-client status sshd
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     0
|  `- File list:        /var/log/auth.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     1
   `- Banned IP list:   x.x.254.115
```

So here we can see that there is one IP in my `sshd jail` (that's my IP)

Also, I can check the Iptables for the rule:

```
> sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  pppgint-254-73-115.b-online.gr  anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

So everything looks good (?).

```
banaction = iptables-multiport
banaction_allports = iptables-allports

# The simplest action to take: ban only
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report to the destemail.
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
            %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]

# ban & send an e-mail with whois report and relevant log lines
# to the destemail.
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, bantime="%(bantime)s", port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
```

And the actions are configured as above.

My problem is that I still can try to SSH (and even login if the parameters are correct) and after my IP is banned.

One problem that I can see in the above configuration, is that in the `source` column in the `iptables` there isn't an IP but there is that weird name `pppgint-254-73-115.b-online.gr`. Shouldn't be my IP there?

Can you help me? If you need anything else, tell me.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is that I still can try to SSH (and even login if the parameters are correct) and after my IP is banned.

Some of the net-filter rules may be wrong, or you have some white-listing rules probably (see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2545#issuecomment-543087971 and below for an answer of similar question).

Check fail2ban.log for the errors after `[sshd] Ban x.x.254.115`. Do you see something?

Also check ssh port (rejecting in iptables) is the single port your sshd answering (may be you changed it in sshd_config).

> Shouldn't be my IP there?

From iptables documentation:

```
 -n, --numeric
    Numeric output.  IP addresses and port numbers will be printed in numeric format.
    By default, the program will try to display them as host names, network names, or services (whenever applicable).
```

So use `iptables -nL`.